# Steps to analyse network issues

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, debug, analysis

I have total strange and somehow random network issues since a firmware update of my router. The thing is that I notice that some streaming services and voice assistants aren't working well. They are connected but they do now work correctly. Alexa is for example responding but not playing music. Disney+ does not work Netflix is working.

This is driving me crazy I would like to analyse what is causing that, but I have no idea where to start. I can surf and ask questions on superuser.

I also restarted all network components including my DNS server (pihole).

Comment: You need to define your setup/network.

Comment: My network contains a lot of components which one are relevant?

Comment: That's for you to decide.

Comment: Well I'm using a FRITZ!Box 7590 and in total 3 switches

Comment: Unfortunately there's really not enough info of your setup for anything else but guesswork, which isn't optimal. The starting point in troubleshooting is simplification. What I'd do is first save the FRITZ and all switch configs as I may need to change them. Next I'd set my system for static IP and Google/CloudFlare DNS, plug it directly to the FRITZ and test. If that works, I'd change the system DNS to FRITZ (I assume it provides the service). If that works, change to DHCP received from the FRITZ (assuming again it provides the service). That works, change system DNS to my own... and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I also restarted all network components including my DNS server (pihole)

You have a DNS server. You restarted it, but what did it achieve? The first thing to check: **Is the DNS server functional?** Can it resolve various domain names you throw at it? Use `dig` or `host` or `nslookup` to check. If it was giving correct results before, there was no need to restart it.

Does it resolve AAAA records as well as A records? Use the `-t` or `-q=` option to test both kinds. Most likely it has two addresses (IPv4 and IPv6) – test both separately.

Are your devices *actually* using it as the DNS server, or are they using something else? (If they're using something else – where did they get that from? DHCP?)

On a computer, if some program is not able to connect to something, install a **packet capture** tool such as Wireshark and take a look at what's happening. If the program is trying to make a TCP connection, you'll be able to see what exact IP address it's connecting to, and then you can use things like ping or traceroute.

If it's instead stuck resolving a DNS name, you'll see which DNS server it's taking to and which name it's trying to resolve – if it's using your Pi-Hole, then the log files of Pi-Hole are the next place, as well as trying to resolve the same name through other servers (same tools as before – dig, nslookup, etc.)

Comment: Oh I totally forgot about IPv6 I think that is a good point. https://test-ipv6.com/ shows me a missing IPv6 connection

Comment: I disabled IPv6 temporary now everything else is working again. Now I need to find out why IPv6 is not working well

Comment: Does your ISP normally provide IPv6 connectivity?  (Even if it does not, everything should naturally fall back to IPv4-only, without the need to explicitly disable v6 support.) If it does – try to ping a v6 host while watching Wireshark packet capture; check whether your router has a v6 WAN address, whether it has a v6 LAN prefix, etc; check whether your hosts have v6 IP addresses, whether they have any _unusual_ addresses, whether their v6 "default gateway" leads to the right device… and check whether a VPN product that you were using might have decided to block IPv6 due to "leaks".

Comment: My IPS has IPv6 dual stack normally. I tested that in the past, not sure why I ran into that connectivity issue. I'll contact the manufacture and my ISP to identify source of the problem. I did no trace routes to be honest, I just notices that I was unable to ping each IPv6 address I checked. The public IPv6 addresses which my network card had assigned was a public one of my ISP, so the prefix was fine.

Comment: I just called my ISP and made a traceroute6. My trace route ends with my router, so it looks like a routing problem. The ISP says there are no issues at their side. I'm waiting now for the manufacture support

Comment: Does the router itself have a ping/traceroute function somewhere? (Does it work, for both outside and inside addresses?) Can you ping/traceroute _from outside_ to either the router's WAN address, or its LAN address, or your Pi's or computer's LAN address? (Use a "looking glass" website such as lg.he.net or lg.sunet.se if you don't have any outside system of your own.)